# SAP Commerce / Hybris denies oAuth login

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

My problem is that the oAuth gets denied on our test server but it works on our live and development (local) servers.
Is there something specific what I have to configure to make it work on antoher server?

I compared the platform folder with test and live, both are identical.
I created same oAuth logins on both servers, didn't work.
I tried to login through the ip, to avoid apache, didn't helped.

Now I am kind of lost where to look next.

To test my login I use Swagger or Postman with this url: `https://test.shop/authorizationserver/oauth/token` with Basic Authorization.
The reponse is: `{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bad client credentials"}` but it is *wrong*.

This is the configuration for the user:
[image]

I had besides this problem, an equal one on the live system. Our apache removed the Authorization from the header to get the Backoffice working, which is protected through the htaccess. When I was researching this problem, I got the same error as this one. Now everything works fine on live. I corrected the same thing on test, tried even uninstall apache, but the login is still not working.

Comment: What error do you get? Which tool are you using?

Comment: Please share exact details of configuration. The oAuth is quite straightforward in hybris.

Comment: @Vikrant which file should i share? Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Could you share exact denial error you get. There will be types of error like user roles, client configuration related error, OAuth2 access error so on.. 
Try the OAuth2 URL directly.. also. 
Check clients configurations.

Comment: I tried to add everything to the problem.

Comment: Please reset client secret then try

Comment: I just removed all tokes and tried again, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need configure oAuthClient for SmartEdit by running following Impex:

```
INSERT_UPDATE OAuthClientDetails;clientId[unique=true];resourceIds;scope[mode=append];authorizedGrantTypes;accessTokenValiditySeconds;authorities;clientSecret;;smartedit;hybris;basic,permissionswebservices,previewwebservices;password,client_credentials;3600;;;
```

For details, please see:
[Configuring oAuthClient for SmartEdit](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/e1391e5265574bfbb56ca4c0573ba1dc/3f675dfd41e642c0b107d0d41efb0fe1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if the configurations are similar? If yes then there is something env specific and needs to be debugged individually.

[image: Oauth Settings]

Comment: As you can see my screenshot is completly identically with yours. I just compared the local.properties with test and live again. They are almost identically, except for some test server specific configuration like ram etc. Do you have any idea where to set the breakpoint is the smartest?

Answer (score 0):

We fixed the problem by pasting the correct "OAuth client secret" into the "Password" and "Verify password" field. This was initialized via impex with an old value (but not visible to the user in the dialog as seen in the lower screen).

[image: Hybris OAuth Client Config]